# Supremum of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider a sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $||f_n||_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}\leq C < +\infty$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it true that there exists a subsequence $\bigl($say $(f_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$$\bigr)$ such that $f:=\sup f_{n_k}$ is finite almost everywhere (Lebesgue measure)?

Comment: If you are not allowed to pass to a subsequence, do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Just take $f_n(x) = \frac{a_n}{(x-q_n)^{1/2}}$, where the $a_n$ are taken such that the uniform integrability property is satisfied on a certain interval $[a,b]$ and $q_n$ are rationals in that interval. Then the supremum of this family on that interval is clearly $+\infty$. In fact the question could've been asked for sequences defined on sets of finite measure, more specifically intervals.

Comment: Yeah ok, I gave an example too but I will delete it. I think I have some progress towards the solution

Comment: Yes I saw the example, I knew also that one (it is called typewriter sequence or something like that if I remember correctly).

Comment: Turns out that there is a counterexample. The construction relies on the properties of the Cantor set... it is very surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 1 in [this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272578/1-s2.0-S0022247X00X00157/1-s2.0-S0022247X0197619X/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIAjJg8ccUXrgAWL51LJoV2vqE5Zvmn8wzF1qFMIn0IItAiEAs8N3mLk2mGy40JoMAr%2BLcLeJRQSI9Js%2FW4fCjfM7cm0qgwQI2v%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDKLOi1VcDKS75a2%2BWCrXAy3kpisPLTxrmkugC29dV3BCBN3MKcJsBxf3jkHr7ClRxURNZd46%2BVWDukwa%2Bhdu9KKi%2FGPmjXuQ9k6KbbPFn2GfCzyPYM7EnY%2F5p0xm56jhgFFtC9zg1zo%2FxR3FECI0b2hIwhhWjB3quNSsRBfYlld7NI9wUxd7t2VjrBzU06eKiqhda5vIVAC3hgdoW8FyO8hCLI69hMR3QGBEyWgiL6zrAOMndXlZng9JgiJwJBU723BPt9gjsKQXSOMDGFWh45Qap10XaZV%2B4GXfuqvgi4AwerOEZtyrFUxjQklWMqQhVlUzcp9AfAzNfgD7lWhyTsZfkMGEvhTBJJycPNY0b5c0gi%2BqJS8K5WpT95dFDU9JOlM0RHbb0q0BVR9TxKtc1jzF6T7d2bf7PuEYTqb6wgns3KcfdcWpNJdLMCZs1yzdj6UzzWhin%2Bk7WW6VaYHLJg5M6DSnZ%2Fx1iZLHd%2FZq1b0mA8FQfiNMaaL8k5ZsWmJLLmXgGIi1ylnIw7qaD7%2B2nM%2FJf9WeGyzADFCchi2Os6jPbzXKKJq%2FikIrc%2FoDK4HdFuqt%2FpB9dy2k6ee3XljKQugXP%2FPVISHL0gHAtxqrUnfWv2e2sOzX4gBWCETkc%2BtTeqlqtdCHUjDShpSNBjqlAffNz4%2FFAQnQh5T%2FNjpEmMT8sJT243UWxxh%2Bv14UThg%2FaVd%2FxhVKdusAUbqahqkhztsk%2BtwM6N4TbUccXuCpsB2CDQqjpbQZPAkWjKmiXXfESmQ30ecHuqfMEayWAwqU0P1orSiSQ%2FOScJsXL8XP8nsRyHJkhp9uu6p86JnIjuQ%2BqFZsyNjgGgnyGO3Xw58fhDRcULAOYtwMWYr%2FxE3Llx%2FDu5VlLA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211129T170920Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYVOBAO72G%2F20211129%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=e5f284ceae8acc64a1ecce0ce2f25d2f797480322b166577c46ed66dae69aaaf&hash=f91dc28a2f24dd0a8086f252cad73ba37f1e85f66d855fc480da38b52610663c&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022247X0197619X&tid=spdf-0bef1f29-f931-4498-b1cd-f3361c9e40e5&sid=a09b225a9f54554e445bed25a93204ea62ebgxrqb&type=client) shows that the answer is negative. Surprisingly, they also prove that the answer is positive if $f_n$ are constant multiples of characteristic functions of measurable sets.